# Looking For KendoUI React Grid Examples to REST data

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

It's not obvious to me how to add real data integration from REST services to KendoUI React Grid. I see an example here titled "Data Operations" but not sure how to deal with REST.  That is, maybe something that supports updating a grid row with REST PUT and adding new rows with REST POST.

Examples?

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples are in the context of React (library for building user interfaces); the grid is a UI component that binds to an array of data (available in its scope) and makes callbacks when user desires to changes something.

There is an example for getting data from a remote endpoint using odata: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/hierarchy/. It is done at the example/application level.

It is not in the scope of an UI element as Grid to perform direct calls to the backend.

Comment: I am also struggling to find examples.   Is anyone aware of examples for "That is, maybe something that supports updating a grid row with REST PUT and adding new rows with REST POST." preferably using the odata api.